# How to set param value dynamically in ExtJs store?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

```
Ext.define('apikeygen.store.Clients', {

extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

alias: 'store.Clients',

requires: ['CCC.model.Client',
           'CCC.util.ActorContext'],

storeId: 'ClientsStore',

model: 'CCC.model.Client',

proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: '/services/clients',

    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'clients.client'
    }
    extraParams : {
       token : dynamica value ----------------> How to set this value dynamically
    }


}
```

});

I have a store like the above in Extjs . How to set the token value dynamically ?

i have the "token" value in Context i can access that value like : `ActorContext.getToken();`

how to assign that `ActorContext.getToken();` to "token" param in Extjs store.

Answer (score 1):

First, the store should be configured with `autoLoad:false` because you do not want it to load  early in the application initialization phase, but only after the token is available.

Then, when you are ready to load the store (token is available) call:

```
store.getProxy().setExtraParam('token', ActorContext.getToken());
store.load();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just assign the value ?

```
var store = Ext.create('apikeygen.store.Clients');
store.proxy.extraParams.token = ActorContext.getToken();
store.load();
```

Comment: as the ActorContext will have value after the user login. but as we are defining the store in the "Application.js" , i think its trying initialize the store when application loads only . So, i am getting error " UncaughtTypeerror: cannot read property 'getToken' of undefined

Comment: this is how i'm doing now.. is it the correct approach ?

Comment: It is much more convenient to call setters/getters instead of accessing properties directly. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

add this in CONTROLLER, or VIEW inside initComponent

```
var store = Ext.create('apikeygen.store.Clients',{
   storeId: 'storeClients',
});
store.proxy.extraParams = { token: 'your data value'};
```

and load your store like this :

```
store.load()
```